# Bundled JS fails - MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: angular, webpack, electron

I'm trying to set up a basic seed for an *Angular / Electron* app. I've worked it up from scratch based on a handful of guides and articles and it works fine whilst developing but fails when I go to build it.

> **Project Source**
>   `git clone https://popClingwrap@bitbucket.org/popClingwrap/angular-electron-seed.git`

If you do `npm start` then `npm run electron` at the same time in a second terminal the app will fire up fine in both a browser and then in an Electron app window. If you click the button on screen it will create a new directory on your desktop so everything seems to be hooked up ok.

If you then do `npm run build` it will bundle everything up without any errors but I thought I should then be able to serve the bundles and see the app run in browser again. However if I do `npm run dev` to start a server in the `/dist` directory I just get a list of errors for both javascript and style sheets saying

> *Refused to apply styles from / Refused to execute script from [url] because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.*

I'll confess I'm struggling to understand the details of a lot of what is going on in this build especially where WebPack is concerned. Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here and what I might try to fix the issue?

Cheers all

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same issue. Have you found any fix?

Comment: Same here :( ..

Answer (score 0):

In the index.html, Please verify whether the below code is same like this(incase if it is missing please add this in index.html) :

`<base href="/">`

This has solved my problem.