# How to use a StencilJs component in ElectronJs

Tags: webpack, electron, stenciljs

Using the Stencil component starter project I created a simple my-component object and published it to npm here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@marekknows/my-component

I then used the electron-webpack-quick-start project to create a simple application that uses the previously mentioned component.  Code here: https://github.com/mmakrzem/myApp

I can start running the Electron App with `npm start` however my-component does not render in the window.  The Stencil documentation (https://stenciljs.com/docs/distribution) describes how to use node modules, however I suspect there is more to it to make this work.

The code that I generate is this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>     
      require("module").globalPaths.push( "C:/Users/mkrzeminski/Documents/webWork/__help/myApp/node_modules")
      require("source-map-support/source-map-support.js").install()
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="renderer.js"></script>
    <div>Hello Electron</div>
    <script src="node_modules/@marekknows/my-component/dist/my-component.js"></script>
    <my-component></my-component>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the Electron (chrome) dev tools says:

`Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:56759/node_modules/@marekknows/my-component/dist/my-component.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

I also don't know how the images found in my component `node_modules\@marekknows\my-component\dist\collection\assets` are supposed to get resolved correctly by Electron.

Comment: Are you sure the path to `my-component.js` is correct? That might explain why the returned MIME type is `text/html`.

Comment: yes the path is correct.

Comment: What's the actual response the browser receives? You can check that in DevTools. Also setting a base might work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603177/bundled-js-fails-mime-type-text-html-is-not-executable-and-strict-mime-ty

Comment: where do I specify the base?  Does that go somewhere in the index.html file?

Comment: Yes, inside `head`. It's to tell the browser the base URL for relative requests (like `node_modules/....`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally get things working by doing the following:

- copy all the assets found in my node package under /dist/collection/assets into my own static/assets folder
- copy all the compiled javascript source code to static/js/

then from the html, if i refer to the code found in static everything resolves correctly.

I don't know why I need to move things around from my node_modules directory into my local application directory, but at least it works!